# MySQL where's the my.cnf path?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I've managed to locate my install directory for MySQL: `/usr/local/mysql/`

Where can I find the path to `my.cnf` to know where I should configure the server?  I've tried creating a `/etc/my.cnf`(as shown below) and it had no affect

```
[mysqld]

#charset
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
character_set_server=utf8
default_character_set=utf8
```

Comment: Specifics about the distro you are using would be helpful.

Comment: Pretty sure debian/*buntu/rhel/cent wouldn't be using /usr/local from a package install. That sounds more like slack or freebsd.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-my-cnf/):

Running this command from the command line / terminal will show where MySQL will look for the my.cnf file on Linux/BSD/OS X systems:

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1
```

This will output something like this:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order: 
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

You can now check for files using the above output at `/etc/my.cnf`, then `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and so on. If there isn't one at one of those locations, you can create one and know MySQL will use it.

Answer (score 3):

On a Linux system 'locate my.cnf" will be the fastest solution.

If there are several my.cnf files, all looking likely (e.g. in `/etc`, `/etc/mysql`, `/opt/mysql/etc`, etc.), then you can run `strace` to see where MySQL binary tries to find its configuration file, but I do think that's an overkill.

Comment: I get `-bash: locate: command not found`... I've tried `find / my.cnf` but it finds nothing.

Comment: This assumes that your locatedb has been updated since the my.cnf file was create. Usually this is done daily via cron. If you need to update it manually run "updatedb" as root

Comment: `locate: command not found` is not an updatedb problem, he doesn't have the package.

Comment: install "slocate" package.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the file your cnf created is being superseded by another one. Check out hte default order below.

From

> mysqld --verbose --help

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 2):

OK a wild shot in the dark:

If the database is installed in `/usr/local/mysql`, then try looking in `/etc/local` for `my.cnf`

Here is how you can tell if you have a `my.cnf`

Run this query `(<= 5.6.7)`

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('wait_timeout',
'innodb_buffer_pool_size','innodb_log_file_size');
```

OR `(>= 5.6.8)` it moved to the performance schema.

```sql
SELECT * FROM PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('wait_timeout',
'innodb_buffer_pool_size','innodb_log_file_size');
```

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
```

If you should get:

- [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) 28800
- [innodb_log_file_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)

  - Default Value `(>= 5.6.8)` 50331648
  - Default Value `(<= 5.6.7)` 5242880
- [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) 134217728

You are running with defaults and there is a possibility that there may not be a `my.cnf` present.

### NOTE:

> [As of MySQL 5.7.6, information available from the tables described here is also available from the Performance Schema. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are deprecated in preference to the Performance Schema tables and will be removed in a future MySQL release. For advice on migrating away from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to the Performance Schema tables, see Section 25.20, “Migrating to Performance Schema System and Status Variable Tables”.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/status-table.html)

Comment: `-bash: updatedb: command not found`

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try again !!!

Comment: `/usr/bin/which: no updatedb in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/java/bin:/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/local/firefox:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/fetter/bin)`

Answer (score 1):

How did you install MySQL and on what platform?

Brute force method on an unixoid OS:

```
find / -name my.cnf -print
```

Comment: I didn't install it, it's on a machine that's a few years old.  It's on `Linux mars 2.6.5-7.147-bigsmp #1 SMP Thu Jan 27 09:19:29 UTC 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

`strace -fe open /etc/init.d/mysql start 2>&1|grep my.cnf` should show you the system call used to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

How are you sure that your cnf file is not being read?

Have you restarted mysqld since the change?

Have you tried to create a new db and looked at its values?

Answer (score 0):

To install locate and updatedb to be able to run it..

Using fedora, centos run as root:

```
yum install mlocate
```

if you are running Ubuntu run:

```
sudo apt-get install mlocate
```

After you finish the install run updatedb
Fedora (as root):

```
$updatedb
```

Ubuntu:

```
sudo updatedb
```

then you can run the locate command as listed above. Again the my.cnf is typically located in /etc. Are you sure mysql is installed? if not do the commands above to install it and replace mlocate with mysqld best of luck!